# How to validate the forms on the submit function, if there are input fields has left on each row

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have problem regarding on my module right now. My question is how I can validate all the input fields has left on each row. Ex. let say I have 5 rows on my table, the first row has completed inputs and then on the second row there are input fields has left. How can I detect that this second row has left input fields.?

Currently I'am using react js for my frontend side and laravel for backend.

Question: How I can validate all the input fields has left on each row

Here is my handleSubmit:

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();

    this.state.rows.map((obj, i) => {

       let obj_amount = obj.amount;
       let obj_bank = obj.bank;
       let obj_branch = obj.branch;
       let obj_check_date = obj.checkDate;
       let obj_check_no = obj.checkNo;
       let obj_customer = obj.customer;
       let obj_remarks = obj.remarks;

    });

}
```

Here is my sample table:

[image: sample table]

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Just one advice. map function is used to return a new array, if you don't want to do it, consider using forEach instead.

Comment: there are multiple ways to do that. 1- Create your input field components with ability to validate each single input independently . 2- You can write your validator function and pass your row to that function. I'm not sure what type of validation you required.

Answer (score 0):

you should use react-metarial-ui-form-validator : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-material-ui-form-validator  it is the easiest way.
If you want to make this without material-ui; I don't know your all code but you can try to create a new function for check the all fields(it is so hard, material-ui has advanced form-validator inside).